# mySQL command with querying multiple database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need help writing a sql cmd that will query theses three tables in my database and return only the items that have an ItemID and a userID in the table cart and then check against a session variable ($sessionuser) that holds the current user, to then only display the items that are in the cart for the specific user.

Table: cart

Column  Type
userID  int(11)
itemID  int(11)

Table: inventory

```
Column  Type
itemID  int(11) Auto Increment   
name    char(24)     
description tinytext     
price   float    
sale    tinyint(1) [0]   
discount    float [0]    
count   int(11)  
image   text
```

Table: users

```
Column  Type
userID  int(11) Auto Increment   
username    varchar(64)  
password    varchar(64)
```

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT inventory.itemid, 
       inventory.NAME, 
       inventory.description, 
       inventory.price, 
       inventory.count, 
       inventory.discount, 
       cart.itemid, 
       cart.userid, 
       users.userid, 
       users.username 
FROM   inventory 
       RIGHT JOIN cart 
               ON inventory.itemid = cart.itemid 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON users.userid = cart.userid 
WHERE  users.username = $sessionuser
```

This is the error im getting right now

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: `Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'` - a string literal has to be marked with single quotes, i.e. the mysql server must receive `WHERE users.username='admin'` instead of `WHERE users.username=admin`. And while you're at it also have a read of http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection